# Asymptotic Series Tail

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty \frac{1}{i^4} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \frac{1}{3n^3},$$ 
meaning that the limit of their quotient tends to $1$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

I don't really know how to go about this, but through testing i have found out that the more general result
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty \frac{1}{i^m} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\sim} \frac{1}{(m-1)n^{m-1}}$$
holds (for integers $m\geq2$), although this hasn't helped me in finding a solution for my initial problem.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Simply use an integral approximation and this should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Note that
$$
\frac 1{j^4} = \int_j^{j+1} \frac 1{j^4} \mathrm dx \geqslant \int_j^{j+1} \frac {\mathrm dx} {x^4},  
$$
thus
$$
\sum_n^\infty \frac 1{j^4} \geqslant \int_n^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dx} {x^4} = \frac 1{3n^3} .
$$
On the other hand, 
$$
\frac 1{j^4} = \int_{j-1}^{j} \frac 1{j^4} \mathrm dx \leqslant \int_{j-1}^{j} \frac {\mathrm dx} {x^4},  
$$
thus
$$
\sum_n^\infty \frac 1{j^4} \leqslant \int_{n-1}^{+\infty} \frac {\mathrm dx} {x^4} = \frac 1{3(n-1)^3} . 
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac 1{3n^3} \leqslant \sum_n^\infty \frac 1{j^4} \leqslant \frac 1{3(n-1)^3}, 
$$
so
$$
\boldsymbol {\sum_n^\infty \frac 1{j^4} \sim \frac 1{3n^3} [n \to +\infty]}. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let natural $\ q\ $ be arbitrary
(e.g. in your specific question, let $\ q:=3).\ $
Then let

$$ \forall_{n=1\ 2\ \ldots}\quad
    T(n)\ :=\ \sum_{k=n}^\infty\,
     \frac 1{{\prod_{s=0}^q}\,(k+s)} $$
Thus
$$\ T(n)\,\ =\ \frac 1
             {q\cdot\prod_{s=0}^{q-1}\,(n+s)} $$
This is virtually the answer to the above QUESTION. We just need to add some $\epsilon$-business so-to-speak. Let's do it.

On one hand:

$$ \frac 1{(k+s)^{q+1}}\ <
    \ \frac 1{{\prod_{s=0}^q}\,(k+s)}\ <
   \frac 1{k^{q+1}} $$
hence

$$ C_n\cdot\frac 1{k^{q+1}}\ <
    \ \frac 1{{\prod_{s=0}^q}\,(k+s)}\ <
   \frac 1{k^{q+1}} $$
where
$$ C_n\ :=\ \left(\frac n{n+s}\right)^{q+1}\quad
     \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}
        \longrightarrow\ 1 $$
Thus
$$ C_n\cdot\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac 1{k^{q+1}}
    \ <\ T(n)\ <
        \ \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac 1{k^{q+1}}\qquad(*) $$
On the other hand

$$ \frac 1{q\cdot(n\!+\!q\!-\!1)^q}\ <\ T(n)
     \ <\ \frac 1{q\cdot n^q} $$
i.e.

$$ D_n\cdot \frac 1{q\!\cdot\! n^q}\,\ <\,\ T(n)
     \,\ <\ \frac 1{q\!\cdot\! n^q}
              \qquad\quad(**) $$
where
$$ D_n\ :=\ \left(\frac n{n+q-1}\right)^q\quad
     \underset{n\rightarrow\infty}
        \longrightarrow\ 1 $$
In the view of the inequalities (*) and (**) the rest is straightforward and routine.

Answer (score 0):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

Since you received good answers to the question, let me go a bit further.

Making the problem more general
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty \frac{1}{i^m}=(-1)^m \frac {\psi ^{(m-1)}(n)}{(m-1)!}$$ where appears the polygamma function. Using the asymptotics for large values of $n$ (you observed the first term)
$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty \frac{1}{i^m}=\frac{1}{(m-1)n^{m-1}}+\frac 1 {2n^m}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\right)$$